# Has anyone successfully integrated Dropbox into a Windows 8.1 Store app, and how?

Tags: sdk, windows-store-apps, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropnet

I have a Windows Store app targeted for Windows 8.1 and I need to integrate Dropbox.  As of now there is still no official Dropbox SDK.  They list some options [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/other).  Some of those SDK's have not been touched in years which is disconcerting.

I also need to authenticate without hitting a server. On iOS I achieve that by having my app register a custom URI with the operating system so that my app gets invoked with a token after the user authenticates in a browser.  Maybe something similar is required on Windows but i can't find any examples where someone set up authentication that way.

So my question is: has anyone integrated Dropbox into a Windows Store app without a separate server to authenticate, and how did you do it?

Comment: Have you looked at https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/04/dropbox-authorization-in-a-windows-store-app/?

Comment: Wow, no, thanks @smarx!  Somehow I missed that.  That seems like it makes the authentication part easy.  Then I still need a way to actually retrieve folder metadata, create folders, upload/download files, and delete files.  I am currently investigating DropNet (http://dropnet.github.io/dropnetrt.html) since I want a higher-level API than the REST calls and I don't believe there is an official Dropbox SDK.

Comment: Yeah, DropNet is probably a good option.

Comment: I am trying to get DropNetRT to work.  The doc says that Windows Store apps can use WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync() to authorize.  I am doing that and I do see the "Connecting to a service" screen, then I log into Dropbox, then click that it is ok for my app to access Dropbox, then it says "Success! <My App> is connected to your Dropbox."  HOWEVER it just hangs there and does not return control to my app.

So I am stuck right now.  I tried a few different redirect uri's.  If I get it working I will post the code.

Comment: The code in my blog post should cover that part, right? Does that code work for you?

Comment: I don't think so.  The reason is that your example uses OAuth 2, and DropNetRT only supports OAuth 1.  The older "DropNet" does support OAuth 2 but I was hoping to use DropNetRT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76106/discussion-between-ty-jacobs-and-smarx).

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sorry, I don't have an example for OAuth 1.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I decided to pursue using DropNetRT. I could not find a complete sample of how to authenticate it in a Windows Store app but I finally have a fully working solution for the authentication WITHOUT A SERVER, which was my goal. I'm posting it here in hopes it will save someone else time.

```
private const string VAULT_KEY_DROPBOX_CREDS = "com.mycompany.dropbox.creds";
private const string AppKey = "myappkey";
private const string AppSecret = "myappsecret";

static private string UserToken = null;
static private string UserSecret = null;
static public DropNetClient Client = null;
static private bool IsLoggedIn = false;

public static async Task<bool> Authorize()
{
    if (!IsLoggedIn)
    {
        // first try to retrieve credentials from the PasswordVault
        PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
        PasswordCredential savedCreds = null;
        try
        {
            savedCreds = vault.FindAllByResource(VAULT_KEY_DROPBOX_CREDS).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // this happens when no credentials have been stored
        }

        if (savedCreds != null)
        {
            savedCreds.RetrievePassword();
            UserToken = savedCreds.UserName;
            UserSecret = savedCreds.Password;

            // since credentials were found in PasswordVault, they can be used to create an authorized client immediately
            Client = new DropNetClient(AppKey, AppSecret, UserToken, UserSecret);
            IsLoggedIn = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // no credentials were found in PasswordVault, so we need for the user to authenticate
            // start with a shell of a DropNetClient
            Client = new DropNetClient(AppKey, AppSecret);

            // build a request uri so the user can authenticate, and configure it to return control to the app when complete
            UserLogin requestToken = await Client.GetRequestToken();
            Uri appCallbackUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
            string requestUrlString = Client.BuildAuthorizeUrl(requestToken, appCallbackUri.ToString());
            Uri requestUri = new Uri(requestUrlString);

            // this call presents the standard Windows "Connecting to a service" screen to let the user authenticate
            // then returns control once the user either authenticates or cancels (uses the back arrow button)
            WebAuthenticationResult war = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, requestUri, null);

            string authCode = null;
            string uid = null;
            if (war.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                // the user successfully authorized the app to use Dropbox, but we are still not done
                // parse the oauth_token and uid out of the response (although the uid is not needed for anything)
                string response = war.ResponseData;
                WwwFormUrlDecoder decoder = new WwwFormUrlDecoder(new Uri(response).Query);
                authCode = decoder.GetFirstValueByName("oauth_token");
                uid = decoder.GetFirstValueByName("uid");

                if (authCode != null)
                {
                    // update the DropNetClient with the authCode and secret
                    // the secret does not change during authentication so just use the one from the requestToken
                    Client.SetUserToken(authCode, requestToken.Secret);

                    // this is the last step: getting a final access token
                    UserLogin finalAccessToken = await Client.GetAccessToken();

                    // now that we have full credentials, save them in the PasswordVault
                    // so that the user will not need to authenticate the next time
                    if (finalAccessToken != null)
                    {
                        UserToken = finalAccessToken.Token;
                        UserSecret = finalAccessToken.Secret;
                        vault.Add(new PasswordCredential(VAULT_KEY_DROPBOX_CREDS, UserToken, UserSecret));
                    }

                    IsLoggedIn = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return IsLoggedIn;
}

public static void Deauthorize()
{
    // to deauthorize dropbox, we just have to find any saved credentials and delete them
    PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
    try
    {
        PasswordCredential savedCreds = vault.FindAllByResource(VAULT_KEY_DROPBOX_CREDS).FirstOrDefault();
        vault.Remove(savedCreds);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // this happens when no credentials have been stored
    }

    IsLoggedIn = false;
}
```